# Attempt to invoke virtual method for checkPermission on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to get the myime of my device and then have it in the form of a String variable.
but i keep getting this error..

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
```

this is my main activity:

```
package com.testflynns82.testPanel;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Funzioni fn = new Funzioni();
    public String imei="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final Button check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imei = fn.checkimei;
                code.setText(imei);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

this is my other java file(Funzioni.java):

```
package com.testflynns82.testPanel;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class Funzioni extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String checkimei() {
        String IMEINumber = "";
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getImei();
            } else {
                IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
            }
        }
        return IMEINumber;
    }

}
```

I found a lot of information and questions similar to mine but I still haven't managed to reach a conclusion, any advice I try to follow I can't solve.

can anyone tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: you are creating an instance of activity `Funzioni fn = new Funzioni()` which is wrong. You don't need a second activity for that. You can do the check in your first activity and you get context once activity is created. So do the check in onCreate

Comment: @Raghunandan i tried some times to put this method directly on the mainactivity but never works but as you say, by putting it inside oncreate its works! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all that in your `MainActivity`. So, here **Funzioni** class is useless.

Please follow the steps in **MainActivity**.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

 
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
        
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);

    }
} else {
    //Read IMEI here
}
```

Then handle the permissions callback here:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
          
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //  Read IMEI here
            } else {
                
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do it on other class, follow this:

```
    public class Funzioni { 
        public String checkimei(Context context) { 
        String IMEINumber = ""; 
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
            TelephonyManager telephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { 
                IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getImei(); 
            } else { 
               IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); 
            } 
        } 
        return IMEINumber;
     } 
}
```

Comment: its right, now works! thanks! anyway and if I need for other reasons to insert this into the functions.java how can I do with the error on the context? is there a solution to this or am I forced to insert everything in the main activity?

Comment: You have to pass context from your **MainActivity**

Comment: Please mark the answer as Accepted and upvote. Thanks

Comment: how to do that? because if i add MainActivity ma = new MainActivity(); on funzioni.java, if i put "ma" as a context inside a method on Funzioni, app show white screen and go in error OutOfMemory

Comment: `public String checkimei(Context context)` , call this from main activity.

Comment: same thing, white screen and after some seconds go OutOfMemory

Comment: ok i see, and now i have the same on funzioni, but on MainActivity to call this function i use: checkimei(mContext); where mContext is getApplicationContext(); its all right? i cant do checkimei(this); because its all inside a OnClickListener and gives me an error

Comment: ok my mistake, now all works fine, thanks so much again for all you support!